# ADD_DEPENDENCIES to different build type

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

Good day, my question about Cmake. Is it possible create dependencies for MSVC project with different build types. Now i have next code in cmake file:

```
SET(LIBRARIES optimized lib_release debug lib_debug)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(lib_release
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "bla bla bla"
COMMENT "Build dep release library")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(lib_debug
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "bla bla bla"
COMMENT "Build debug library") 
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib_release)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib_debug)
```

This worked perfectly but if i want to create only release version i will get excess step build of debug version library which not needed for release, this library not linked to my target(release), but time to build it i spend very much. My question is next: is it possible specify which dependencies i use for release and which for debug something like this:

```
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib_release optimize)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib_debug debug).
```

Answer (score 0):

cmake will recognise the build type you set by the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug|Release etc` command. Then you can use `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ")` for compile time flags and so on like so:

```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/Zi /Od /D \"_DEBUG\" /D \"DEBUG\" /RTC1 /MDd") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "/MD") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi")
```

You can also set linker flags with `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} <flags>)`

Individual targets can be addressed as well in a similar manner

```
  set_target_properties(yourexe PROPERTIES
                      LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "<FLAGS>"
                      LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "/DEBUG"
                      LINK_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "<FLAGS>"
                      LINK_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "<FLAGS>")
```

This [file](https://github.com/maidsafe/MaidSafe/blob/master/cmake_modules/standard_flags.cmake) will help you see some options for different OS's.